# Exception with source filter in DirectShow (0x80040241)

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, directshow, directshow.net, source-filter

```
var m_FilterGraph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
int hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(file, "Ds.NET FileFilter", out capFilter);
```

When my project is x64 it will throw System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040241): The source filter for this file could not be loaded. With x86 everything is OK.

It's c# code but the problem is present in every x64 app i've got to build ds graphs.
examples:
https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21105/DSGraphEdit-A-Reasonable-Facsimile-of-Microsoft-s

When i build graph by hand (ex. File source async. -> LavSplitter -> some decoder -> Enhanced Video Render) it's working.
So it's rather system problem than code, but x64 video players that i've got are working ok o.O so i don't know... Maybe somebody has an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

32 and 64 bit environments have their own set of filters. They start with similar stock filters and then you install additional filters for 32 bit, 64 bit or both. When you have 32 bit filter installed, and there is no corresponding 64 bit filter, then you you have situation as described in question: Win32 works fine, x64 does not work. Install missing 64-bit filters to have it resolved.

Comment: can i check somehow what filters are needed? cuz as i said, i am able to make a correct graph to play files - by hand... only when i ask for autobuild of a graph there is a problem...

Comment: You can certainly check by using 64-bit version of GraphEdit or similar.

Comment: 64bit graph by hand: http://i.imgur.com/zA5U7t4.png, 64bit graph by open media file: http://i.imgur.com/FT3C5xf.png . so how i can check why this is not working?

Comment: Manually you build the graph the way you like. Automatically, filters are supposed to register themselves  to  properly advertise their capabilities. Apparently, this is not the case here. I would expect something is missin in LAV filters here.

Comment: hm everything is working on my laptop, even with lav filters and x64... but on my desktop i still have this error. I'm comparing now installed filters by hand and they seems to me to be similar :/